# Understanding float and how and when to float an element in CSS3?

Tags: css, css-float

I am unable to get my head right on this property. 
First, I tell you what knowledge I do have regarding this.
I am focussing on `<p>` element with `id="amazing"` for this thread.

[image]

Now I give it a width

```
#amazing{
   width: 200px
}
```

The result is:

[image]

Since the paragraph is a block element, so no elements are going to move up beside it because all block elements have line breaks before and after them.

Now i float it by:

```
#amazing{
       width: 200px;
       float: right
 }
```

My understanding upto this part:

***(1) First, the browser flows the elements on the page as usual, starting at top of the file and moving towards the bottom

(2) When the browser encounters the floated element, it places it all the way to the right, it also removes the paragraph from the flow just like it's floating on the page***

[image]

Correct me if I am wrong till here...
Next,

***Float property with CSS drop down menus***

Consider this snippet taken from the web :
***an unordered list with list items*** like this

```
             <ul id="menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="">About Us</a>

                    <ul id="menu-about-us">
                        <li>
                            <a href="">The Team</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="">History</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="">Vision</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="">Products</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="">Cozy Couch</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="">Great Table</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="">Small Chair</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="">Shiny Shelf</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="">Invisible Nothing</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="">Conatct</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="">Online</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="">Right Here</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="">Somewhere Else</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

[image]

Now if i do like this,

```
ul {
    font-family: Arial, Verdana;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    /*list-style: none;*/
}

ul li {
    display: block;      
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
li ul {
    display: none;
}
```

[image]

For ul li, doesn't ***display: block*** will make them behave as block elements, But i see them as inline elements as shown in the figure. What good thing does ***float property*** does here?

```
ul li {
        display: block;      
        position: relative;
        float: left;
}
```

I seem to be too much perplexed. Kindly help me out...
It would be better if someone clears this concept in context to how ***float*** will behave with *block and inline* elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the scenario and on what you would like to achieve Shirgill.
I've prepared for you quick comparision on JS Fiddle --> http://jsfiddle.net/Lt7cftyc/

You're right. The behaviour of list when you set display:inline-block; to list with float attribute is very similar:

```
ul li {
display:inline-block;
}
```

will behave similar to:

```
ul li {
display:block;
float:left;
}
```

but there are some differences. For example you need to always clear floated elements to prevent unexpected behaviour:

```
clear:both;
```

In my example below, you can see different scenarios with inline and floated menu. You can play with it and see how it's gonna behave when you add margins or paddings to inline element and to floated element. You will be suprised.

```css
ul.inline li {
 display:inline-block;
}

ul {
    font-size:14px;
    font-family: Arial;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: lightblue;
    margin: 20px 0;
}

ul li {
    padding: 0 5px;
}

ul.floated2 {
    height: 20px;    
}

ul.floated li, ul.floated2 li {
    display:block;
    float:left;
}

.clr {
clear:both;
}
```

```html
<p>This is example of inline list</p>
<ul class="inline">
    <li>menu 1</li>
    <li>menu 2</li>
    <li>menu3</li>
</ul>
<br />
<p>This is example of floated list. Note that there is no backgroud - first difference!</p>
<ul class="floated">
    <li>menu floated 1</li>
    <li>menu floated 2</li>
    <li>menu floated3</li>
</ul>

<br />
<p>This is example of floated list. The background is visible, but after I set height:20px;. </p>
<ul class="floated2">
    <li>menu floatedSecond Version 1</li>
    <li>menu floated 2</li>
    <li>menu floated3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What exactly is the role of clear: both in your example shown above? Secondly, in the case of ui when you don't set its height, a horizontal line is shown as in case of ui.floated element. Please, may you extend a little bit.

Comment: You right Shirgill when I was writing this example I added 'just in case' those divs. I've already updated this example. But I would like to show you when you need to use clear:both; so I prepare an example for you with comments. Sorry if I consfused you and hope this example will be more clear for you. http://jsfiddle.net/p7p5hk3b/

Comment: excellent mike. So, whenever i use float property, then after it i need to clear them as well as to avoid an element getting on top of another.

Comment: Yes, after last floated element insert clear element.

Comment: one more thing mike, can i now say that block elements behave as inline elements when i float them.

Comment: In some way, they have, but there are differences with padding or margins. You need to style them differently, but again yes, you can achieve pretty the same result when using display:inline-block not display:inline. In depends on particular case. When I build navigation bar I always use float elements with display:block; instead of inline. Back in the days IE has trouble with properly render display:inline, so developers could use either float property or display:inline-block;